# Probability of random walk returning to 0

Tags: probability, random-walk

Given a symmetric 1-dimensional random walk starting at 0 -- what is the probability of the walk returning $k$ times to 0 after $2N$ steps?

I know that the total number of paths it can take is $2^{2N}$. My problem is finding the total number of paths returning to 0. Also, since you can only return at even $k$'s, the no. of possible hitting points is $ {{N}\choose{k}}.  $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the first return time to $0$. The generating function $E_0(s^T)$ of $T$ for the random walk starting at $0$ is such that $$E_0(s^T)=sE_1(s^T),$$ where $E_1(s^T)$ is the generating function of $T$  for the random walk starting at $1$. By the same first-step argument, $$E_1(s^T)=\frac12s(1+E_2(s^T)),$$ where $E_2(s^T)$ is the generating function of $T$ for the random walk starting at $2$. By the Markov property, $$E_2(s^T)=E_1(s^T)^2.$$ Solving this system    in $E_0(s^T)$, $E_1(s^T)$ and $E_2(s^T)$ yields $$E_0(s^T)=1-\sqrt{1-s^2}.$$ Thus, the generating function of the $k$th return to $0$ starting from $0$ is $$E_0(s^T)^k=\left(1-\sqrt{1-s^2}\right)^k.$$
These functions have series expansions in powers of $s^2$. The probability that the $k$th return to $0$ occurs after exactly $2N$ steps is the coefficient of $s^{2N}$ in $E_0(s^T)^k$, that is,
$$
(-1)^N\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^i{k\choose i}{i/2\choose N}.
$$

Comment: But what if the $k$th return happens before $2N$ steps? Will we need to calculate this for all possible $k$th returns for $2M \leq 2N$?

Comment: You could do that, or use the identity $\sum\limits_nP(R\leqslant n)s^n=E(s^R)/(1-s)$, valid for every integer valued nonnegative random variable $R$.

Comment: [For posterity] How we got to the first equation: for convenience denote by $T_{i,j}$ the first return time to $j$ starting from $i$. Then $\mathbb{E}[s^{T_{0,0}}] = \mathbb{E}[s^{T_{0,0}}|X_1 = 1]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) +  \mathbb{E}[s^{T_{0,0}}|X_1 = -1]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = -1) $. Now if $X_1 = 1$, $T_{0,0} = 1+T_{1,0}$ and similarly if $X_1 = -1$, $T_{0,0} = 1+T_{-1,0}$. So $\mathbb{E}[s^{T_{0,0}}] = \frac{1}{2}( \mathbb{E}[s^{1 + T_{1,0}} ]+ \mathbb{E}[s^{1 + T_{-1,0}}]) =  \frac{1}{2}s (2\mathbb{E}[s^{T_{1,0}}])$ by symmetry, which gives the required result.

Comment: The expression for $\mathbb{E}_1[s^T] ( = \mathbb{E}[s^{T_{1,0}}])$ is obtained in exactly the same manner. Next we have $\mathbb{E}_2[s^T] = \mathbb{E}[s^{T_{2,0} } ] = \mathbb{E}[s^{ T_{2,1} +T_{1,0} }]$ since the walk must necessarily go through $1$ if it goes from $2$ to $0$. Then $\mathbb{E}_2[s^T] = \mathbb{E}[s^{T_{2,1}}]\mathbb{E}[s^{T_{1,0}}] =(\mathbb{E}[s^{T_{1,0}}])^2$ as $T_{2,1}$ and $T_{1,0}$ are independent and identically distributed.